# there should be no special character in encryption output in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace RestService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IRestServiceImpl" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestServiceImpl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
         UriTemplate = "xml/{id}")]
        string XMLData(string id);
        //

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "json/{id},{id2}")]
        int JSonSum(string id, string id2);
     //
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,

            UriTemplate = "json/{userID},{firstname},{lastname},{phoneno},{email},{password}")]
        int JSonRegisterUser(string userID, string firstname,string lastname,string phoneno,string email,string password);
        //Get All Users
        //[OperationContract]
        //[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        //    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        //    UriTemplate = "GetAllUsers/")]
        //IEnumerable<Users> GetAllUsers();
    }
}
```

//I have created Restfull webservice. when I invoke that service then email address with @ sign creates problem. then I send encrpted email address but encryption result has slashed,spacial character or @ then again facing same error 404
I am using base64 for encryption

Comment: Encryption algorithms generally return byte arrays, not characters, so any unwanted characters that are introduced are to be blamed on your encoding scheme.  Maybe you want to use base64 or just hex.